# No consigo que mi variable se declare con mi for of y su if dentro de una función

Tags: javascript

Tengo la función siguiente dentro de un módulo, y no consigo que me funcione; el fallo es el siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "eventName", eventFound is undefined
> loginToEvent http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/Class/Event.js:97
> loginToEvent http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/Class/Event.js:85
> InitApp http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/main.js:23
> <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/main.js:14

Mi función es esta:

```
export let eventFound;

  export function loginToEvent() {
 
  let loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");
  let btnLogin = document.getElementById("btnLogin");

  let user = loginForm.name.value;
  let password = loginForm.password.value;
  

  btnLogin.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (const event of events) {
      if (event.userName == user && event.password == password) {
        eventFound = event; //ME DA ERROR DICE QUE NO SE ENCUENTRA..
      } else {
        console.log("NO ES POSIBLE CONECTAR")
        break;
      }
    }
    if (
      eventFound.eventName == user &&
      eventFound.password == password &&
      eventLog == false
    ) {
      console.log(`Evento encontrado ${eventFound.eventName}`);
      openForm(btnLogin, eventPanelSection, loginForm);
      console.log("Login realizado correctamente");
      console.log("Bienvenido " + user);
      loginUser.reset(); //Limpia el formulario despues de haber logeado
      eventLog = true;
    } else if (eventLog == true) {
      console.log("Ya estas logeado");
    } else {
      console.log("Vuelva a intentarlo");
      console.log("No se ha podido logear, vuelva a intentarlo.");
    }
  });
}
```

Para ver todo mi código en github pueden ir [aquí](https://github.com/jdluis/PromoterListApp/tree/Remodeled-from-scratch).

Pueden [probar](https://jdluis.github.io/PromoterListApp) además la app, el fallo se lanza cuando le das al botón continue del formulario Login.

He probado de todo pero no consigo saber por qué me lanza el error, quiero decir: creía que era por el scope, pero no conseguí solucionar nada moviendo la variable, luego hice varios cambios y tampoco. Yo creo que tiene que ver con el module, ya que soy nuevo usando los export y import y seguro que se me salta algo. Lo curioso es que en mi versión mas vieja tengo una función muy parecida y sí me funciona, pero en este caso no hay manera...

Comment: Pero que es `events` en esta linea `for (const event of events) {`? No veo events definido, por lo tanto, para mi no entra en ese for, cuando llega al siguiente if, ahi es donde saca error, como `eventFound` es indefinido y el condicional es `if(eventFound.eventName == user)`, `eventName` no se puede acceder si `eventFound` es indefinido (que es exactamnte lo que dice el error)

Comment: No, no podemos ver el código ;) Igual, las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas porque, si algún día borras el repo, deja de servirle a los demás. Como te indican, no es evidente que `events` exista y sea un array. Te has planteado que puede llegar vacío y deberías validar ese escenario?

Comment: Con poner un [punto de interrupción](https://ibb.co/02m1RBs) como te muestro en la imagen tienes. Debuguear debe ser tu primer acercamiento a enfrentar un problema. Como menciona @Pipe, eventFound no está definido cuando llega al `if`.

Comment: Tienes razón con lo del repo, pondre aquiy el array que si está definido en mi codigo: let events = [];

Answer (score 0):

com, como bien dice @Alfabravo, lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta es poner todo el código referente a tu pregunta en el post, porque aunque la repo de github es interesante para analizar tu pregunta, esta puede desaparecer y si alguien entra en esta consulta dentro de un tiempo porque tenga una consulta similar, le faltaría información. Dicho esto, y como te ha apuntado @Pipe, el error dice exactamente lo que te está pasando.
Te voy a explicar lo que te ocurre y como solucionarlo:
Te adelanto que tu código funciona bien, el problema es de concepto.
Cuando creas un evento, guardas este en la matriz "events" y una copia en LocalStorage. Cuando inicias la app, lees el LocalStorage y cargas "events" con el contenido.
Cuando llegas al login, compruebas si algunos de los eventos que hay guardados en "events" coincide con el usuario y contraseña que hay en el formulario y si coincide asignas a "eventFound" el evento, si no coincide sales con un "break" después de poner un mensaje en pantalla.
Hasta aquí ningún problema, pues "events" tiene contenido y puede hacer esa asignación, el problema lo tienes cuando en LocalStorage no hay nada y por tanto la variable "events" está vacía. Cuando llega al "for", **este no se ejecuta porque "events" no tiene nada** y la función continúa, lo siguiente que se encuentra es un "if" que hace referencia a "eventFound", que como no ha pasado por el "for" anterior, no está asignada o lo que es lo mismo está "undefined" y eso es lo que te está diciendo el error.
Solución:
Tienes que comprobar **antes del for** que la variable "events" tenga algo y si no es así, salir de la función. Por ejemplo:

```
if (events.length == 0) {
     console.log("Todavía no hay eventos guardados");
     break;
}
```

De esta forma, evitarás el error. Puedes comprobarlo de la siguiente forma, crea un evento e intenta loguearte después, no hay error. Cierra la ventana y abre una nueva e intenta loguearte directamente, no hay error pues los eventos del localStorage han cargado "events". Ahora abre una nueva ventana de incognito, con lo cual el localStorage no está activo, e intenta loguearte, error pues "events" está vacía.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, a todos! me ha valido bastante la explicación de cada uno, en temas de debug aun tengo que aprender mucho, veía que el fallo estaba ahí pero no entendía por qué, ahora entiendo mas el concepto como tu dices, voy a probarlo